# Wie kann ich "swipe" am besten übersetzen?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich übersetze eine Bedienungsanleitung, aber ich finde keine gute Übersetzung für das Wort `"to swipe"`.

Es handelt sich hierbei um `"swipe on the screen up or down ..."`, wie man es von der Benutzung eines Smartphones (z.B. iPhone) mit Touchscreen kennt.

Ist die Übersetzung `"streichen Sie auf dem Display nach oben oder unten ..."` in Ordnung? Bessere Vorschläge?

Comment: [scrollen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/scrollen)?

Comment: @Em1: Trifft es nicht ganz, weil nicht eine Seite gescrollt wird, sondern auf einen anderen Bildschirm gewechselt wird (eine vollkommen andere Ansicht) Unter scrollen verstehe ich eher dass ich mich im gleichen Dokument hoch oder runter bewege.

Comment: Ah, verstehe. Ich hab's nich so mit Smartphones ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im Windows-8- und Metroumfeld sind die Begriffe **Swipen** und **Pinchen** oft benutzt:

- **Swipen** = **links wischen**, **rechts wischen**, **Wischgeste** nach oben und nach unten.
- **Pinchen** = Zusammenziehen von Zeigefinger und Daumen, was zu meiner Kenntnis keine Übersetzung hat.

Sie auch zum Beispiel [dieser Artikel](http://www.it-techblog.de/gestensteuerung-unter-windows-8-mit-diesen-wischbewegungen-werden-tablets-gesteuert/04/2012/) vom deutschen IT-Techblog.

In der Dokumentation von Microsoft finde ich jedoch diese Begriffe nicht im Deutschen. Siehe dafür der MSDN Artikel [Übersicht über Windows' Touch-Gesten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd940543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), der die verschiedene Gestenbewegungen auflistet.

Comment: Also bräuchten wir auch noch einen Begriff für ***"to pinch"***: *"kneifen"* fände ich nett. Aber das versteht dann wieder niemand (*"ich kneif' immer mein Smartphone"*). :D

Comment: @Takkat: `Kneifen` verstehe ich besser als `pinchen`, zumindest wenn ich eine Ahnung habe, was es bedeuten könnte, also die Geste schonmal gesehen habe. `Quetschen` wäre so ähnlich.

Answer (score 9):

Zwar könnte *"streichen"* die gewünschte Übersetzung sein:

> **Streichen** Sie mit Ihrem Finger über das Display, um...

Unter *"streichen"* versteht man jedoch im Allgemeinen eher eine behutsame Bewegung; ganz anders als es mit *"to swipe"* zum Ausdruck kommt. Mein Vorschlag wäre also:

> **Wischen** Sie **rasch** nach oben oder unten über das Display, um...
>   **Mit einer schnellen Wischbewegung** nach oben oder unten können Sie...

Wir brauchen *"schnell"* oder *"rasch"*, um den Unterschied zu *"to wipe"* besser herauszuarbeiten.

Comment: Finde "wischen" auch die beste Übersetzung dafür.

Comment: +1 für Wischen. Vielleicht wird dann der ein oder andere Nutzer dann die ganze Hand benutzen, aber das kann man ja noch näher spezifizieren (muss man sowieso, wenn es verschiedene Gesten mit verschiedener Fingeranzahl gibt).

Answer (score 3):

Einige weitere Vorschläge, wobei ich mich nicht mehr an das Wort *to swipe* anlehne.

> *Zum Wechseln der Ansicht, **fahren** Sie mit dem Finger über den Bildschirm.*
>
> ***Ziehen** Sie den Finger über den Bildschirm, um zwischen den Ansichten zu wechseln.*
>
> *Um zur nächster Anzeige zu schalten, **bewegen** sie den Finger in die gewünschte Richtung über den Bildschirm.*
>
> *Blättern sie mit einer **Fingerbewegung** auf die nächste Seite.*

Answer (score -4):

'Swipe' ein Reinigungsmittel aus den 70igern, welches 'an der Tür' verkauft wurde. Ein Konzentrat als Allzweckreiniger. To swipe ... wischen.

Comment: Wieso 'an der Tür'? Wieso nicht an der Tür?